# How to add progress indicator like wifi settings in listview in android

Tags: java, android

I am able to display available wifi list in my android app...for displaying available wifi list i am using expandablelistview in my app...but i want add progress indicator image in my app..like wifi settings..If wifi connected i want to display connected status below the wifi ssid...how can i do this?

```
         List<ScanResult> List = wifiManager.getScanResults();
         ArrayList<String> scannedList = new ArrayList<String>();
         for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
             if (List.get(i).SSID.matches("")) {
                scannedList.add(List.get(i).SSID);
                scanlist.append(List.get(i).SSID);
            } else {
                scannedHomeAps.add(String.valueOf(List.get(i).SSID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom listview with textview and imageview. There are plenty of examples in internet. For instance:

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

The result doesn't look beautiful, but it works, so you can redesign later.

Comment: Thanks bro...design i will do it..no problem